# Grep for displaying count of muliple strings in a single file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

Another question ... Can I get the count of items that are unique .. If in my previous case, i just took a simple instance . My business req is here ...
I have string like the below                                                                  happy=7
happy=5 
happy=5, 
bascically I will be using regex for searching the word happy, I would give like "happy=*"... I need the output as "count of happy =2" as there is one duplicate instance ...

Comment: This makes no sense.  If your input is `h=5\nh=5\nh=7\nh=7\nh=7\ns=1\n`, do you want output `h=2\ns=1\n` or `h=3\ns=1\n`, or `h=2\n` or `h=3\n`?

Comment: Also, is your string all on one line, each data point on a single line, or mixed?  You originally mentioned using `grep` which implies line oriented data, but now grep is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```
awk '/happy/{ happy+=1 } /sad/ {sad += 1 } 
    END { print "happy =", happy+0, "sad = ", sad+0 }'
```

Note that like `grep -c`, this does not count occurrences of each word but the number of lines that match each word.

Comment: Another question ... Can I get the count of items that are unique .. If in my previous case, i just took a simple instance . My business req is here ...                                                                    I have string like the below                                                                  happy=7  happy=5 happy=5, bascically I will be using regex for searching the word happy, I would give like "happy=*"... I need the output as "count of happy =2" as there is one duplicate instance ... I have edited the ques .. Plz look at that for clear picture

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using something like perl or awk, where you can increment counters based on conditional statements.